# Reverse Proxy for IP Camera

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm using an Amcrest camera which requires basic auth to render its stream ([documentation](https://s3.amazonaws.com/amcrest-files/AMCREST_CGI_SDK_API.pdf) - page 17). The camera is accessed through `http://admin:password@IP_CAMERA/cgi-bin/mjpg/video.cgi` .

When I try to hit `:56700`, I am prompted for auth even though it's hardcoded (below). Even when I enter the correct credentials, it fails. What am I doing wrong?

```
    server {
        listen 56700;
        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass http://IP_CAMERA/cgi-bin/mjpg/video.cgi;
            proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic xxx";
        }
    }
```

I've also tried adding `proxy_pass_header Authorization;` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65308098/679449).

Comment: I think that you have mixed the `rtsp` syntax with the `http` syntax, try `http://<ip>/cgi-bin/realmonitor.cgi?action=getStream&channel=<channelNo>&subtype=<typeNo>` for `http` and then authenticate with username and password OR use `rtsp` with `VLC` with this syntax `rtsp://<username>:<password>@<ip>:<port>/cam/realmonitor?channel=<channelNo>&subtype=<typeNo>`

Comment: @CrazyTux I can hit the URL above in my browser without any issue

Answer (score 2):

As said above it can be solved by

```
proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==";
```

where `dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==` is result of command: `echo -n "user:password" | base64`

**i guess you already tried that**

anyway, i believe correct location will looks like

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://IP_CAMERA;
    proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==";
    proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic $http_authorization"; # For interactive mode
}
```

without `/cgi-bin/mjpg/video.cgi` because it will passing at browser or http client side

**OR** If it doesn't work for you, it can be related to this case
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14839712/nginx-reverse-proxy-passthrough-basic-authenication

If Camera have some realm checks you can know expected Realm via Dev Tools at Headers tab - Response headers section.

But you will need compile nginx with `headers-more-nginx-module`

You can make it with this script

```
cd /usr/src
NGINXFILE=$(wget -qO- http://nginx.org/en/download.html | tr ' ' '\n' | egrep -o 'nginx.+?tar.gz' | head -1)
wget http://nginx.org/download/${NGINXFILE}
tar zxvf ${NGINXFILE}
cd ${NGINXFILE%.*.*}

cp -r /etc/nginx /root/nginx_$(date +%F) #Backup current nginx configs

cd /usr/src
git clone https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module.git

./configure --add-module=/usr/src/headers-more-nginx-module --prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --modules-path=/usr/lib64/nginx/modules --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-compat --with-file-aio --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_slice_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_v2_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-stream --with-stream_realip_module --with-stream_ssl_module --with-stream_ssl_preread_module --with-cc-opt='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -fPIC' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie'
make
make install
```

once it done you can try such config:

```
location / {
  proxy_http_version      1.1;
  proxy_pass_request_headers on;
  proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
  proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

  more_set_input_headers  'Authorization: Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA=='; 
  #more_set_input_headers  'Authorization: $http_authorization'; # For interactive mode
  proxy_set_header  Accept-Encoding  "";

  proxy_pass              http://IP_CAMERA;
  proxy_redirect          default;
  more_set_headers        -s 401 'www-authenticate: Basic realm="Authentication Required"';
}
```

where `www-authenticate: Basic realm="Authentication Required"` your actual data of this header

I checked both cases, it works for me, i tested it on custom flask application. Unfortunatelly i have not such camera for personal debug

Answer (score 1):

**Edit with Amcrest-specific solution**

At some point (around 2017?) Amcrest [released a firmware update that **removed Basic Authentication**](https://amcrest.com/forum/ip-cameras-f18/cgi-sdk-no-longer-functioning-on-17r--t2401-s30.html?sid=c14a95ec9a41e962e48ccc22c64d0f01#p11563) from their IP cameras, leaving Digest Authentication as the only option.

[This Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65610992/) may be your best option for stripping the Digest Authentication out like you want using FastCGI and nginx.

Either that or perhaps you can find a way to downgrade the firmware on your camera to support Basic Authentication again.

---

**Previous Answer**

Are you Base64-encoding the username and password with a colon in between?

For [HTTP basic authentication](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Client_side), you will need to do the following:

> `proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic xxx";`

Replace the `xxx` with `Base64(<username>:<password>)`. That is, find yourself a Base-64 encoder, enter the username, a literal colon (`:`) character, and the password, and replace the `xxx` with the resulting string.

For example, if the username is `admin`, and the password is `hunter2`, we could run the following at a Bash prompt:

`printf %s 'admin:hunter2' | base64`

and put the resulting string in the header like this:

`proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic YWRtaW46aHVudGVyMg==";`

Comment: The username and password is being Base64 encoded with a `:`, yes.

Answer (score 0):

*Shot in the dark*

I know sometimes if the file permissions are not set correctly you can get a sign-in box which in some cases is for the file permission level and not connection level if that makes sense.  Perhaps that's what's happening is some kind of file permission issue on the web server end?  You can end up with two different credentials a connection/service based one and then the file level one if the connection/service does not have file permission.